# IOS Swift How can I get SearchBar Text value on View 1 to View 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar

I have 2 Controllers: Controller1 and Controller2 which serves as a SubView . Controller1 has a UISearchBar attached to it and OnClick Controller2 shows up as a SubView with a TableView . As a user types in the SearchBar I can get the results using this

```
 // Controller1
   @IBOutlet weak var mySearch: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySearch.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
        if let text = searchBar.text {
            let search = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            _ = search

        }
    }
```

Now my biggest issue is getting the value that I get in **searchText** and passing it over to Controller2, How can I go about doing this ? Controller2 does an HTTP Post request and will use the value of the SearchText in Controller1 . This is the code in Controller2

```
 class Controller2:  UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var TableSource: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TableSource.dataSource = self

   // I would like to get value of SearchText here so that I can
   // send it as a parameter in my HttpPost request

    session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {

        } else {
            do {

                // get Json Data

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
            print(self.locations)
        }

    }).resume()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Registration_Search", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}



 }
```

This is in Controller1 and on tap of the UISearchBar this is how I get Controller2 as a SubView

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
           Location_Search.showsCancelButton = true

        let Popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Controller2") as! Controller2
        self.addChildViewController(Popup)
        Popup.view.frame = self.Controller2.frame
        self.view.addSubview(Popup.view)
        Popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: What is the hierarchy of viewcontrollers like? Do both have different navigation controllers, or the same ones?

Comment: They are just 2 different ViewControllers no navigation Controllers

Comment: Two different View controllers that are inside of what? They have to be in something or in some form of hierarchy in order for you to need access to both of them at the same time.

Comment: I am new to Swift but I just updated my code and essentially they are connected by a SubView that comes into view when you first tap the SearchBar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
           Location_Search.showsCancelButton = true

        let Popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Controller2") as! Controller2
        self.addChildViewController(Popup)
        Popup.view.frame = self.Controller2.frame
        Popup.textFromSearch = mySearch.text
        self.view.addSubview(Popup.view)
        Popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        return true
    }
```

and in your **Controller 2** just after the IBOutlet add var:

```
var textFromSearch = ""
```